# Inheritance of modules and their type

Tags: inheritance, types, module, ocaml

I have defined 2 signatures and 2 modules as follows. One signature is derived from another; one module is derived from another.

```
module type MATRIX =
sig
  type 'a t
  ...
end

module type AMATRIX = 
sig
  include MATRIX
  ...
end

module MatrixArray : MATRIX =
struct
  type 'a t = 'a array array
  ...
end

module AMatrixArray : AMATRIX =
struct
  include MatrixArray
  let init (x: 'a) : 'a t =
    Array.make 2 (Array.make 2 x)
  ...
end
```

But when I compile this, it gives me an error in the end `Error: This expression has type 'a array array but an expression was expected of type 'a t = 'a MatrixArray.t`.

Does anyone know how I could keep this inheritance and make the type `'a t = 'a array array` recognized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `MatrixArray` is slightly more than just a `MATRIX` : it's a `MATRIX` where the implementation of type `t` is known to be an array. So you can write :

```
module MatrixArray : MATRIX with type 'a t = 'a array array =
struct
  type 'a t = 'a array array
  ...
end
```

This way, you keep the `MATRIX` constraint and can detect type errors, as well as keep information about what the type actually is - assuming, of course, that you care about making the type public instead of abstract.

Answer (score 5):

In the code:

```
module MatrixArray : MATRIX = struct
  type 'a t = 'a array array
 ...
end
```

You force `MatrixArray` to hide the definition of `'a t`. One way to solve your problem is to remove the signature constraint:

```
module MatrixArray = struct
  type 'a t = 'a array array
 ...
end
```

You can later replace `MatrixArray` with `(MatrixArray : MATRIX)` when you want to abstract the type `t`.

Comment: In this case, the type of `MatrixArray` is no more `MATRIX`, I can't use `MATRIX` to constraint `MatrixArray` any more... it will be a pity, no?

Comment: you can still use `MATRIX` to constraint `MatrixArray` later. You just write `(MatrixArray : MATRIX)` instead of simply `MatrixArray` where you need `t` to be abstract

Comment: I don't think so... If I write `(MatrixArray : MATRIX)` after the declaration of `MatrixArray`, and recompile the code, it still stops at the function `init`, and gives the same error...

Comment: Of course, because if you write `include (MatrixArray : MATRIX)`, then you still abstract the type `t`. In this case you don't want `t` to be abstract as you are calling `Array.make` functions. So in this case, just keep `include MatrixArray`. If you really want to keep `t` abstract, then you need to export a constructor (which will work for any type `t`) in `MATRIX` and call that abstract constructor in `init`.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with putting too much abstraction: it is nice to hide types (i.e. to use abstract types), but the OCaml compiler uses manifest types to perform some optimizations. Abstracting types will prevent the compiler from performing them.

One example, that might be interesting in your case, is that OCaml has two representations of arrays : standard arrays, and flat arrays of floats. If the compiler knows the type of the elements in an array, it can directly access the array using the correct representation. But if types of the elements are abstract, the compiler will add a test to choose between the two representations.

If you are working with matrices of floats, you should keep the types manifest, so that the compiler will generate the most efficient code when accessing these arrays.

An example:

```
let init_array t x =
  for i = 0 to Array.length t - 1 do
    t.(i) <- x
  done
```

is much slower (in native code) than

```
let init_float_array t (x : float) =
  for i = 0 to Array.length t - 1 do
    t.(i) <- x
  done
```

because `init_array` is polymorphic and `init_float_array` is monomorphic on float arrays.